# Is a strictly monotone continuous function defined on $\mathbb{R}^m$ has a continuous inverse?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $F: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a strictly monotone, surjective, continuous function. Here, the strict monotonicity means that $(x - y)^T (F(x) - F(y)) > 0$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ as shown at

[Is every monotone map the gradient of a convex function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111767/is-every-monotone-map-the-gradient-of-a-convex-function)

Then, by strict monotonicity of $F$, it is also injective, and hence bijective. So, there is its inverse function $F^{-1}: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$.

My question is "**Is the inverse $F^{-1}$ also continuous?**"

When $m = 1$, it seems true as shown at

[Prove that if f is a continuous strictly monotone function defined on an interval, then its inverse is also a continuous function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775093/prove-that-if-f-is-a-continuous-strictly-monotone-function-defined-on-an-interva)

Many thanks in advance for your answer and discussion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Any* continuous bijection $F:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^m$ has continuous inverse.  This is (a special case of) a famous theorem known as [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is helpful the local inversion theorem, that is a consequence of Dini's Theorem for systems. It states that if $f:A \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, $A$ open set, $f \in C^1(A)$ and $x_0 \in A$.
If $\det J_f(x_0) \neq 0$ then there exixts $\sigma, \delta>0$ and a unique function $\varphi$ such that
$$
\varphi: B_\sigma(y_0) \rightarrow B_\delta (x_0)
$$
is $C^1$ in $B_\sigma(y_0)$,
$$
\varphi(f(x))=x,\quad f(\varphi(y))=y,\quad \forall x \in B_\delta (x_0), \quad\forall y \in B_\sigma(y_0)
$$ where $y_0=f(x_0)$.
Here the inverse is $\varphi$ that belongs to $C^1(B_\sigma(y_0))$, so in particular $\varphi$ is continuous over $B_\sigma(y_0)$. Your function $F$ is invertible then satisfies the hypothesis $\det J_f(x_0) \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think invertibility of $F$ is not enough to have det$J_F(x_0) \neq 0$ for all $x_0$ as $F(x) = x^3$ is invertible, but det$J_F(0) =$ det$0$ = $0$.

Comment: ok but if you add the hypothesis of convexity for F then everything should work