# Is $f(x)=x+\sin x$ a homeomorphic function?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, inverse-function

I want to determine $f(x) = x+\sin x$ is homeomorphic  or not on $\mathbb{R}$?

A bijective continuous function is homeomorphic  if its inverse is also continuous.
I know that $f$ is bijective. Also $f$ is continuous being the sum of two continuous functions.

How to look for the continuity of $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Which properties?

Comment: continuity of both sides.

Comment: The statement follows from [the inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem).

Comment: @ José Carlos Santos see the edited part.

Comment: @freakish Not quite: the derivative vanishes at $x=(2k+1)\pi$, $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f$ is continuous and strictly increasing, because its derivative is $\ge0$ and is positive on the intervals $(\pi+2k\pi,\pi+2(k+1)\pi)$.

This its inverse function exists and is strictly increasing as well and defined over $\mathbb{R}$ because $f$ is neither upper nor lower bounded. In particular $f^{-1}$ has left and right limit at every point, because
$$
\lim_{x\to c^-}f^{-1}(x)=\sup\{f(x):x<c\}
\qquad
\lim_{x\to c^+}f^{-1}(x)=\inf\{f(x):x>c\}
$$
Suppose that at some point $c$ the two limits are different, say
$$
\lim_{x\to c^-}f^{-1}(x)=\sup\{f(x):x<c\}=a
\qquad
\lim_{x\to c^+}f^{-1}(x)=\inf\{f(x):x>c\}=b
$$
with $a<b$. Then $(a+b)/2$ doesn't belong to the codomain of $f^{-1}$, which is the domain of $f$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Once you know that $f$ is strictly increasing, just use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775093/prove-that-if-f-is-a-continuous-strictly-monotone-function-defined-on-an-interva?rq=1).

If you want to know some regularity of $f^{-1}$, continue reading.

Let $N=\{(2k+1)\pi:k\in\mathbb Z\}$.

In $\mathbb R\setminus N$ you have $f'\neq 0$, so $f$ is actually a diffeomorphism.
Now we have to investigate what happens near $N$. By translation, it is sufficient to examine what happens around $\pi$. By Taylor expansion, we have that for $\epsilon>0$ small enough
$$
|f(x)-f(\pi)| = |x+\sin(x)-\pi| \geq \left|\frac{(x-\pi)^3}{12}\right|
\qquad \forall x\in(\pi-\epsilon,\pi+\epsilon)
$$
so the inverse $f^{-1}$ is $\tfrac13$-Holder near $\pi$.